# Bootstrap login not fitting mobile correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, authentication

I'm using a template to create a Bootstrap login page and it doesn't want to resize for mobile devices, but instead turns out to be a very tiny login form like this:
[image]

When it **SHOULD** look like this:

[image]

here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <link href="lib/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="lib/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="lib/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="lib/js/winmarkltd-BootstrapFormHelpers-d4201db/dist/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h2> Your Company</h2>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid formThis">
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <h2>Login Here</h2>
        </div>
        <form id="loginForm" class="form-signin" action="login.php" method="post">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="Username" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="User Name" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br>
            <button id="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                Sign in</button>
            <a href="#" id="signUp" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up</a>
        </form>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <div id="signUpModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Register For An Account</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" id="profileForm" action="register.php" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">First name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="Jane" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Last name:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Doe" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="jane." type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Role</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="group_role" placeholder="Role" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" data-toggle="tooltip" title="If 'Salesman', enter sales region otherwise leave blank.">Region:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="region" placeholder="region" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Department</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="department" placeholder="Department" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Email:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="email_address" placeholder="janesemail@gmail.com" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Phone</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="555-123-4567" class="input-medium bfh-phone form-control" data-format="+1 (ddd) ddd-dddd">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Password:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Confirm password:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="confirm_password" type="password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Request" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send Request</button>
                                        <span></span>
                                        <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" id="cancel" type="reset">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/js/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/winmarkltd-BootstrapFormHelpers-d4201db/dist/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Styles:

```
.navbar-default{
    height: 100px;
}

body {
    background: #eee !important;    
}

.wrapper {  
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.form-signin {
    max-width: 380px;
    padding: 15px 35px 45px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);  

    .form-signin-heading,
    .checkbox {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .checkbox {
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    .form-control {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: auto;
        padding: 10px;
        /*@include box-sizing(border-box);*/

        &:focus {
            z-index: 2;
        }
    }

    input[type="text"] {
        margin-bottom: -1px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    }

    input[type="password"] {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0;
        border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Don't use max-width. just use bootstrap grid system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Browser will use screen width of mobile device only if you declare this inside of `<head>` tag.

Comment: Oh...  I feel so dumb.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="wall">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <h2>Login Here</h2>
        </div>
        <form id="loginForm" class="form-signin col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" action="login.php" method="post">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="Username" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="User Name" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br>
            <button id="login" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
                Sign in</button>
            <a href="#" id="signUp" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up</a>
        </form>
        </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: I'm familiar with the grid system and tried it too.  I just tried your code...  It resizes with my screen as it should, but when I go to 'view as mobile device' it goes small.  I've never seen this before.

Comment: just remove your max-width, and just add your grid system.